# Installing 14.04 (64bit) and restoring certain config files from 12.04 (32bit)

Tags: virtualbox, backup, system-installation

I currently have a 12.04 LTS (32bit) installed alongside Windows. I've also set-up **virtualbox** inside my current Ubuntu installation. Well, I know that a simple `sudo update-manager -d` will get me through to the latest LTS release but not onto a different architecture.

Having said that; I'm planning on a fresh install of 14.04 (64bit) to avoid further issues as I do not have spare time look through. Since its completely a different architecture; What I'm concerned is about certain settings and applications whether those will fit into the new one. One of my main objectives is to keep `virtualbox` settings as I've done few tweaks and mounted/shared drives into the guest VM(s).

I've used **Deja-dup** to backup my home folder but it has so many unnecessary configs such as wine which I don't even need it. What I would like to know is that, apart from the below shown image (`.config` & `VirtualBox VMs`) what else do I need to back up.. (Note: Necessary files from home folder are copied mostly, but still any advice will be appreciated).

[image]

Comment: Is `VirtualBox VMs` the directory you have set as "Virtual Machine Folder" in the virtualbox preferences? If you want to keep the shared drives, you also need to keep the sharing configuration. How are these shared? Using the virtualbox shared folders feature or using something like smb or nfs?

Comment: `VirtualBox VMs` are just profiles I guess but the exact VM's are on a separate partition location. Shared folders are on a partition and shared using Virtual box's sharing option. those are pretty basic.

Comment: We can't help unless you explain what you have where. Obviously, you need to copy the VMs as well. The `VirtualBox VMs` directory is something you created manually, how can we know what's in it?

Comment: No! `VirtualBox VMs` directory will be created on its own in default. But the location of the exact VMs can be specified manually despite the default folders. Apart from that what I would like to know is that, what else I would consider copying except for the ones shown above.

Comment: So, is `VirtualBox VMs` the directory you have set as "Virtual Machine Folder" in the virtualbox preferences? Not in the VM's settings, but in virtualbox's preferences. It should be enough to copy that folder, AFAIK, virtualbox does not store anything in `.config`.

Comment: You misunderstood. `VirtualBox VMs` is basically a default folder to store files soon as a user creates a guest VM despite you give another location to store `.vdi` file. I do know it doesn't store under `.config` file.

Comment: I know. But that's just the default, for example, I don't have that on my system and instead I have everything in `~/.VirtualBox/` and machines are in `.VirtualBox/Machines`. Anyway, all you need to backup is the VirtualBox folder.